# What Files to Deploy to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, gwt

What files do I need to have to deploy a GWT web app to Tomcat, preferably in a War?

Can't quite distinguish if Build.xml is actually needed when there is already a 'war' folder when you create a new app via the wizard in Eclipse.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With recent versions of GWT (1.6 and up, maybe even 1.5) you only need to include what's in the `war` folder. You can just war up that folder (zip it up and give it a `.war` extension).

If you're using the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/), you may even be able to try right-clicking on the project and selecting "Export -> WAR" (I'm not really sure about this though, I'll verify when I get into work, in about an hour).

You definitely do not need `build.xml` in there.

Comment: export -> WAR is definitely OK

Comment: Can't find export to War in the list?

Comment: Export WAR actually didn't work for me (you need to have the WTP extensions for Eclipse to use it). I can select it, but it's not exporting the correct files, as it doesn't seem to understand Google's project structure. Let me look into this further.